# 3 vertical background images appear as one image with content in center image. Center image "cuts off" and does not match footer image

Tags: html, css

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/djDWF/84/

The problem is, the inner container (text-padding) margin/width for the text/images is affecting the center background image. The repeated image that touches the footer does not extend to full height, and cuts off so the center and footer images do not match up (it is kind of hard to tell, but if you add or remove text in my jfiddle example you can see the center image change where it meets the footer.).

This is for a school project, and though I did not need to actually do this type of image background, I got this far so might as well continue. I don't want to use javaScript if possible because that is not part of the course yet.

I tried removing the text wrapper and styling each p tag individually but the same effect occurs.

I also tried mathematical combinations using line-height and margins. If I set the line-height to equal the right and bottom margins, and the left margin to equal the height of the footer then the effect works, but because my footer image is so large this is not a workable solution.

Mathematically I tried to keep the same ratios with the footer height but this did not work either (or else I did this wrong. I tried dividing each by the same amount.)

Is there any way to do this using only CSS and and not having to resort to tables?

Comment: Your problem is kind of unclear to me. The background is nice and joins up nice (not worse than you could achieve).

Comment: what browser are you testing in?  As Mario stated, I don't see any broken background images or background images not connecting to the header/footer images.  It looks like one complete piece of (old) paper in Chrome.

Comment: I understand. Basically you can see a line showing up at the footer separation. Reason being the repeated centre background isn't fully showing it's last repeat --- With that said, does it need to be variable or do you know how much text you will be putting in it? If not you can just set a height: `div#background-center{height: 1604px;}` or whatever height is right to fit your final text - http://jsfiddle.net/djDWF/85/. Let me know if this is what you wanted and I'll put it down as a solution.

Comment: That does indeed work, and I feel like an idiot for not thinking of it, heh... however is there any way to make this center image "liquid" based on the content (while still matching the footer) or is that going to require JavaScript? Of course since I only have a couple pages I could just make a new div for each page heigh req.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**So in short the problem is:** You can see a line showing up at the footer separation because the repeated centre background isn't fully showing it's last repeat as the container isn't big enough.

**The solution:** If it doesn't need to be variable and you know how much content you will be putting in you can just set a height: Live example - http://jsfiddle.net/djDWF/85.

```
div#background-center{
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/gsNFa.png) repeat-y;
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    height: 1604px; /* add this */
}
```

Obviously, pick whatever height is right to fit your final text.

With your current images there is no way to do this automatically without using JavaScript.

Comment: I understand now, I will just use a separate div for each page since the "report" is only a few pages any ways. Thank you.